# Dual National exiting Mexico with Expired Passport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, dual-nationality, canadian-citizens, mexican-citizens

My daughter is a Mexican & Canadian citizen, born in Mexico. She has a valid Canadian passport, but her Mexican passport has expired.

We are travelling to Mexico, from Canada, soon. Too soon to renew her Mexican passport. I've done some research and she can enter Mexico with an expired Mexican passport. We're bringing some back up identification.

We're planning on leaving one week after we arrive, so there may not be time to get her passport renewed while we are there, and, ideally, we'd rather not spend the little time we have there in the passport office.

Can she leave Mexico with an expired Mexican passport and valid Canadian passport?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=mx&DE=mx&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Nationals of Mexico are allowed to enter with an expired
>      passport.

In addition:

> Passport Exemptions: Nationals of Mexico with a:
>
> - national ID card
> - certified copy of birth certificate
> - consular registration
> - certificate of Mexican nationality
> - Matricula Consular
> - Constancia de Identificacion

Because these are requirements for **entry** to Mexico, I just called immigration at Mexico city airport, who said that, if you enter Mexico on a Mexican passport, you also have to exit on a Mexican document, and expired Mexican passports aren't accepted for **exit**, **but** the listed alternative documents, if valid, **are**.

So if your daughter has a valid Mexican national ID card (*cédula de identitad personal*) or birth certificate, for example, she can leave Mexico.

All of this said, Mexico does not do exit border checks at airports, so if anyone it is the check-in/gate staff that will be enforcing the rules. If they don't want to check you in/let you board as a Canadian without an FMM, present a Mexican document

Comment: My experience is that if you try to check in for an outgoing flight with a foreign passport with no FMM the airline staff will withhold the boarding pass until you go to an immigration office and come back with the form. She will pretty certainly need to show both the foreign passport and proof of Mexican nationality to get a boarding pass without the FMM, or she could enter as a Canadian to get an FMM.

Comment: @Dennis Fine, then simply show a Mexican national ID card or birth certificate (for example) like I said

Comment: @Crazydre Thanks for this answer AND for calling immigration at the Mexico City airport! We ended up entering and exiting on her Canadian passport, but we brought some extra documentation in case any additional questions were asked, but it was smooth. Thanks!

Comment: OP can also fly to Tijuana and exit through the land border, thus avoiding all border formalities.